# how to send albums as new messages in telethon

Tags: python, telegram, sendmessage, telethon

I want to send every new message from one channel to another.
But when there are albums in the message, they are sent separately to the destination channel.
How can I send them as an album (as one message)?

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage('your_channel'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    await client.send_message('my_channel', event.message)
```

And I used `events.album` instead of `events.NewMessage`, but it didn't work!

Comment: You need to detect if a message belongs to an album by checking the `grouped_id`, and if they do, you need to manually reconstruct the list of media and captions used.

Comment: @Lonami can you give me an <code> example please ?!

Comment: You have to check `if event.grouped_id is not None`.

Answer (score 0):

I find a simple way, maybe someone will use it

```
@client.on(events.Album(chats="your_channel"))
   async def handler(event):
       await client.send_message(
           "my_channel", #output channel
           file=event.messages, #list of messages
           message=event.original_update.message.message, #caption
       )
```